# Event is null after having it checked for being not-null

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, event-handling

Suppose there is the following code snippet (I am using .NET 4.0):

```
private void CauseTrouble()
{
    if (MyEvent != null)
    {
        DoSomeIrrelevantCalculations();
        MyEvent();
    }
}
```

When running a fairly large program containing this (simplified) method, in rare cases I encounter a NullReferenceException from MyEvent(). The debugger tells me that MyEvent is null even though I just checked that it is not null. What is going on here?

Now some people might immediately say: "Of course, if you have a multithreaded application, another thread might unregister myEvent before those irrelevant calculations are finished and - Boom! - you have a NullReferenceException!"

That is surely true, but before I venture deeper into the darkness of multithreading (since it is a very rare error, I often have to wait days for it to occur again), I need to know if there are any other possibilities for this to happen?

Specifically: **Does an event being null after a successful non-null check *necessarily* mean that another thread has unregistered the event?**

(Another option I could imagine is the external unmanaged code which is executed by the program as well and which has already caused some data access violations before. Is it possible that some operation there is causing the pointer to MyEvent to be overwritten? Or should this be impossible since the code snippet is part of the managed code? I am too inexperienced with that stuff to be able to tell.)

If you say now: Hey, why do you not log all register/unregister processes and check what is going on yourself: You are right. I am already on it. But as I said, with a bit bad luck it can take a week before I get an answer, and I want to check out other possibilities as well in the meantime.

**Update**

Things get stranger. The assumption was correct, the debugger shows that MyEvent is indeed null when being called. So I did what was recommended here and replaced

```
if (MyEvent != null)
{
    DoSomeIrrelevantCalculations();
    MyEvent();
}
```

with

```
var handler = MyEvent;
if (handler != null)
{
    DoSomeIrrelevantCalculations();
    handler();
}
```

But this still yields a NullReferenceException. Debugging shows that MyEvent is again null when handler() is called, but handler itself is not. How can a NullReferenceException be evoked if the object is not even null?

Comment: It's better to actually set the event to a temp variable and then check that for `null` and call it instead to avoid the race condition, though the fact that you have code that runs between the check and the call to the event is somewhat fishy.  Another work around that some might use is to subscribe one no-op method to the event so that it is never null.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use

Comment: [Great article from @JonSkeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/)

Comment: @juharr: That will surely fix the exception, although the event should never be null anyway (if it happens, that is a serious bug in my program). So I am looking for possible causes why this could happen. Is a race condition the only possibility where this can happen, or can (for example) the unmanaged part of the code also cause trouble, like overwriting addresses in the managed part of the code? If I can be sure that there must have been an unsubscription of the event, I will also have to implement a lock on the event call, not only an exception handling.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options. If you're working in C# 6.0 or higher, you can use the null coalescing operator. Behind the scenes, it'll prevent this problem from happening. Here's how:

```
MyEvent?.Invoke();
```

The other option is useful if you're not using C# 6.0. Just store it in a variable first, check the variable, and then invoke it using the local variable, like this:

```
var eventHandler = MyEvent;
if (eventHandler != null)
{
    eventHandler();
}
```

Comment: There are other options in here: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, while this is valuable advice and surely solves the problem of the NullReferenceException, it is not quite the answer to my question. The question is if something else than the event being unsubscribed - especially some unmanaged code issues - could also lead to the event being null, or if I can be sure that it is an unsubcription issue caused by another thread. But I agree fully that my example in fact IS flawed code and should be modified in the way you are suggesting (unfortunately I am using C# 5.0, so no null coalescing operator).